# Using tokens to authenticate a one-time download link?

Tags: api, token

I am trying to create a download link to an ASSET in craft that I can send via email - the client clicks the email link (which has a token query string attached to validate the link) and is presented with a Craft page to download the attachment.

**But** I keep getting a 404 error, saying invalid route.

- Im trying to create a token - which will only last for say 24H.

`{% set token = craft.app.tokens.createToken() %}`

I am aware that you need to pass in arguments to createToken() but I am not sure what they are as the docs are somewhat highlevel:

https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-services-tokens.html#public-methods

- Store the token in Craft *(haven't worked this part out yet)*
- Send a link, with the token as part of a query string

`<a href="<PAGE_URL>?token={{ token }}">Download here</a>`

- When the user visits the page, the twig template **1) gets the query string:**

  {% set token_from_queryString = craft.app.request.getQueryParams('token')|first %}
- 2. Validates that the query string is the same as the one stored and so presents the download link to the user:

### LOGIC TEST

```
  <div>
    {% if token == token_from_queryString %}
      <p>Token matches - download file:</p>
    {% else %}
      <p>Seems that the link used is no longer acspected, please create a new one:</p>
    {% endif %}
  </div>  
</div>
```

Issues:

1. I don't know if this is actually viable using this option.
2. if I do not include the query string in the URL i.e. do not add ?token=(token value or a fake value) - then the page works as exspected. But if I add the query string I get given a 404 route error.
   How am I supposed to be formatting the tokens route, is this were the token lives? or a route to be directed to via the link. I haven't found any Craft docs on this as of yet.

-- Update of work:

I have got most of this code to work, but still am having issues with the route of the TOKEN and hiding the original URL of the ASSET.

ISSUES:

A) Does Craft automatically store tokens, if so where? I saw reference on discord to storing them in the DB, but no docs to back this up yet.

B) I set the route to be the file URL in hopes it could be used in a `<a href="{{ tokenA }}" download>{{ download.title }}</a>`, but this says that the  file cannot be found. But if I use "getToken" variable below, that uses `getTokenRoute()`, then it spits out the original URL of the download. So the token route is set to the URL (maybe I could be misunderstanding), but the token cannot be used to route to a download path.

This is all with the goal of validating the user via a token and hiding the URL of the original download file.

URL needing to be used:

```
https://<your site address>/<page with this code on it>?tokenA=<the token number produced by tokenA (also printed to the page at TOKEN CODE:>
```

Code below

```
<main>
<h2>TOKENs</h2>

<div class="wrapper" style="background:lightblue">
  {# Get file #}
  {% set download = craft.assets().fileName('<NAME OF FILE TO BE USED AS ONE TIME DOWNLOAD>').one() %}

  {# Create token - ISSUE A) B) #}
  {% set tokenA = craft.app.tokens.createToken([download.url]) %}

  {# Gets the Token from the query string #}
  {% set queryString = craft.app.request.getQueryParams('tokenA')|first %}

  {# Takes the original token path - and gets it #}
  {# R) download path of the asset - download #}
  {% set getToken = craft.app.tokens.getTokenRoute(queryString)|first %}

  <p>TOKEN CODE: {{ tokenA }}</p>
  <a href="{{ tokenA }}">Download</a>
  <p>Result of get token: {{ getToken }}</p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>Params</h2>
  <div class="wrapper" style="background:lightskyblue">
    <h1>{{ getToken }}</h1>

    {# If getToken has length i.e. it has been found #}
    {% if getToken|length %}
      <h1>Working</h1>
      {# <a href="{{ getToken }}">link</a> #}
    {% else %}
      <h1>Broken</h1>
    {% endif %}

      {# <p>getQueryString(): {{ param }}</p>
      <p>getQueryParams(): <br> 
        {% for block in param2 %}
          {{ block }}<br>
        {% endfor %}
      </p>
      <p><strong>getQueryParams('token')|first: {{ param4 }}</strong> <<< WINNER</p>
      <p>getQueryStringWithoutPath(): {{ param3 }}</p> #}
    
  </div>
</div>



<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>LOGIC TEST</h2>

  <div class="wrapper" style="background:lightyellow">
    {% if getToken|length %}
      {# If token is valid allow the user to download the below - #}
      {# ISSUE: need to hide the original url of the download so it cannot be shared - #}
      <a href="{{ download.url }}" download>{{ download.title }}</a>

      {# Delete the used token from the system (this doens't seem to be working) #}
      {{ craft.app.token.deleteTokenById(getToken) }}
    {% else %}
      <p>Seems that the link used is no longer acspected, please create a new one:</p>
    {% endif %}
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: This _seems_ like it’d be a viable approach, where you’d want to store the token’s ID after creating it. That way, you could retrieve its value with `getTokenById()`. For issue #2, have you tried `&token=[value]` instead of `?token=[value]`? Don’t know offhand how the route should be formatted as an argument, but you’ll probably find examples in Craft’s source.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the help - turns out there is very little mention of createToken in the Craft source files - which has also been mentioned on the discord. Adding the & instead of the ? does work, but I think it now believe the path should include the token as part of the sites address and not a query string. I'll update the question with an example.

Comment: To be fair, you’re working with something Craft uses more internally. The good news is there are examples in the source to follow, like this: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/f45c185f4aa0d164f40fbdb34061d0150256ef1c/src/console/controllers/UsersController.php#L414-L419

You could mimic that pattern, including the use of that `UrlHelper::urlWithToken()` method to build the URL.

Comment: @MattStein - thanks again for the reply and looking over the question, its really appreciated. I also, found out why the ?token= was not working. I had stupidly set a variable to the name of "token" which Craft seemed to dislike rather alot.

Comment: I dunno @Wally, “token” sounds reasonable to me even if it turned out to be a problem. It sounds like you’re closer to the goal, at least!