# How to generate a token, retrieve it and delete it

Tags: yii, api, token

I have a workflow were a user will be given a link, with a token attached to it, upon clicking that link, the token will be read from the query string, if it is valid the user will be presented a download link and the token will be deleted.

If the token is not valid (or has been deleted) - then the User will be shown an error page.

Process I am using to achieve this (and the issues):

1. create a token. ***(this issue is blocking so needs to be resolved first)***

https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-tokens.html#public-methods

From the docs it says that you can set a route as the first argument when creating a token. But when I use the token in a URL it gives me an error - Steps to reproduce below:

```
// Route to a template
Craft::$app->tokens->createToken(['template' => 'template/path']);
```

I am writing this in TWIG:

```
  {# Create token #}
  {% set token = craft.app.tokens.createToken("https://<website>.ddev.site/DEV/downloadToken") %}
```

I then attach the Token to a url to present to the user as part of the URL querystring:

```
<a href="https://<website>.ddev.site?token={{ token }}" target="_blank">URL LINK</a>
```

I would suspect that when I visit this link, the token routes me to the route I set in the token variable? But I always get a 404 error: Caused by: **Invalid Route – yii\base\InvalidRouteException**

[image]

So, could someone please give me an example of a valid route? and retrieving it.

If there are any questions then please let me know :)

Also: note - This is a support question for [Using tokens to authenticate a one-time download link?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/39909/using-tokens-to-authenticate-a-one-time-download-link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `['template' => 'template/path']` syntax in the doc block is incorrect (will get that updated).

If you want to route to a template and you want to do this from Twig, it'd be something like:

generate.twig

```
{% set token = craft.app.tokens.createToken(['templates/render', {template: 'claim'}]) %}
<a href="claim?token={{ token }}">Claim</a>
```

claim.twig

```
You did it.
```

Then request to claim with a valid token will get the usageCount/expiry logic applied to the token.

Comment: HI Brad, thats amazing thanks so much for spotting this. Could I be a bit of a pain and ask for a follow up please. Could you provide me with the code that would allow me to set a max use of this token to 1 use. Also (sorry) - is there a way to get a token by the querystring? I am trying to get the token by what is provided in the query string - see if it is valid (has not expired or hit its max use) and if it has then delete it (if it is valid then show some data) - I've been looking at the docs, but have spent alot of time on this so any help would be really great - thanks again :)

Comment: could I please ask you to update your answer to include one more bit of formatting: How do you add a "$usageLimit" to the token creation? I thought it would look like this:  {% set token = craft.app.tokens.createToken(['templates/render', {template: "/downloads/_one-pager"}], 1) %} ? Thanks